# How do I implement a periodic Task that queries the db and deletes row periodically?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

How do I implement a periodic Task that queries the db and deletes row periodically? I want to do this so that I prevent my database from growing too big over time.

Comment: use alaramManger and Intent Service to do periodic task. if you want code then i give you full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Sticky `Service` with `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` is what you need.

```
public class MY_SERVICE extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     // remove last alarm you set
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, MY_DB_PROCEDURE_BROADCAST.class);
    intent.setAction("myDbProcedure");
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);

    // add new alarm manager
    intent = new Intent(context, MY_DB_PROCEDURE_BROADCAST.class);
    intent.setAction("myDbProcedure");
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct, 1, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),
            intervalMin*60*1000, alarmIntent);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

your `BroadcastReceiver` class :

```
public class MY_DB_PROCEDURE_BROADCAST extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String TAG=getClass().getName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Started");
        // DO YOUR DB TASK HERE
    }
```

}

In your manifest define the service and broadcastReceiver:

```
<service
        android:name="MY_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

 <receiver android:name="MY_DB_PROCEDURE_BROADCAST" android:enabled="true"/>
```